# PHP not outputting special characters properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8

My query selects a row from my database and outputs in form of JSON to the browser, but I have encountered a problem that I can't twist my head around: whenever the row that's being selected by my query contains a special character such as "ö", "ä" or "å" the response from php becomes completely blank. Here is my query:

```
"SELECT email, firstname, lastname, phone, role FROM members WHERE id=? LIMIT 1"
```

I output it like this:

```
$data = array(
                    "email" => $email,
                    "firstname" => $firstname,
                    "lastname" => $lastname,
                    "phone" => $phone,
                    "role" => $role
                );
                   echo json_encode($data);
                   exit();
```

If I manually replace a part of the output with a special character like this:

```
$data = array(
                    "email" => $email,
                    "firstname" => "Jörgen", <-------------
                    "lastname" => $lastname,
                    "phone" => $phone,
                    "role" => $role
                );
                   echo json_encode($data);
                   exit();
```

Then it outputs it properly. My `config.php` contains this:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

And my database collation is set to `utf8_general ci`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include `$db_connect->set_charset("utf8");` in your PHP code when connecting to the database. (where `$db_connect` would contain your database  connection)

Comment: I connect like this: $conn = new mysqli($database['host'], $database['user'], $database['pass'], $database['db']); where would I include your suggestion?

Comment: right below that line, as `$conn->set_charset("utf8");`